# Android CheckBox do not listen OnCheckedChangeListener on restore fragment state

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my android app I have **fragments** & in one of fragment I have **checkbox**. 
This **checkbox** has listener like this, that shows **alert dialog** on check:

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
      if (isChecked) {
           alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.is_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                  NItem item = new NItem();
                  item.isOk = 1;
                  setItem(item);
              }
           });
           alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.is_not_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                   NItem item = new NItem();
                   item.isOk = 0;
                   setItem(item);
              }
           });
           alertDialog.show();
       }
   }
```

When I check **checkbox** & go to **other fragment** & go back to **fragment** where this **checkbox**, the method `onCheckedChanged` is called again. I think it is because **fragment** **restored** from **saved state**. How to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should detect when user **touches** your **checkbox**, and only handle `onCheckedChanged()` when the **checkbox** is touched.

Here is an example:

```
static Boolean isTouched = false;

yourCheckbox.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                isTouched = true;
                return false;
            }
        });


//Listen to checked change, but only if the toggle is touched, not when initializing the toogle
yourCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isTouched) {
            //Do your things
            isTouched = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `onCheckedChanged()`, check the fragment's `isResumed()` and only continue if it's true. That's much simpler than checking if the view is touched and will cover any cases where you want the listener to handle `setChecked()` calls. If you don't want the listener to pick up those calls, you can remove the listener before the call and add it back after.

`isResumed()` returns true if the fragment is in the resumed state (`mState >= RESUMED`). When `onCheckedChanged()` is called during the restore, it is in the `ACTIVITY_CREATED` state.

Here are the various states from the Fragment class:

```
INITIALIZING = 0;     // Not yet created.
CREATED = 1;          // Created.
ACTIVITY_CREATED = 2; // Fully created, not started.
STARTED = 3;          // Created and started, not resumed.
RESUMED = 4;          // Created started and resumed.
```